# Why can't this header location thing works

Tags: php

```
function actionExit()
{
    $fake =  file_get_contents("fake.txt");
    $header='Location: '. $fake; 
    file_put_contents ("data.txt",$header); //It shows Location: http://google.com
    header($header);
    exit();
}
```

The file data.txt contains Location: http://google.com

However, it doesn't show anything just a blank screen.

Comment: enable `display_errors`, what's the warning that's been shown?

Comment: First step _always_ is to take a look into your http servers error log file. You cannot program php in a web environment without monitoring that log file.

Comment: I'd say that `file_put_contents` fails because your file permissions aren't correctly set. Check the Server error log files to see the cause.

Comment: Code is works for me please confirm you are calling the function as well .

Comment: What `curl -v {target url}` shows?

Comment: Make sure your code doesn't already displayed something before it calls `header()` (it fails if some text was already sent). A whitespace, a newline or a [UTF-8 BOM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) put by the editor in front of the `<?php` marker is enough to cause troubles. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); before `header()` to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can't write your file due to missing permissions, so that `file_put_contents()` fails.

You can check it with [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writeable';
} else {
    echo 'The file isn\'t writeable';
}
```

If the file isn't writeable, you can set permissions with [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: That is exactly what the problem is.

Comment: It's a classy one and one of those things you should check first when writing files.